# How a mutex inserted into a structure or linked list in C language actually works. What is inside details?

Tags: c, multithreading, struct, linked-list, mutex

How a mutex variable inside a structure or linke list actually takes effect. Does it locks the complete structure ? Actually when it's declared inside a structure then how it works ? what are inside details of it's working ?

Here is an sample code from oracle site :-

```
    typedef struct node1 {
    int value;
    struct node1 *link;
    pthread_mutex_t lock;
    } node1_t;
    node1_t ListHead;
    node1_t *delete(int value)
    {
    node1_t *prev, *current;
    prev = &ListHead;
    pthread_mutex_lock(&prev->lock);
    while ((current = prev->link) != NULL) {
        pthread_mutex_lock(&current->lock);
        if (current->value == value) {
            prev->link = current->link;
            pthread_mutex_unlock(&current->lock);
            pthread_mutex_unlock(&prev->lock);
            current->link = NULL;
            return(current);
        }
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&prev->lock);
        prev = current;
    }
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&prev->lock);
    return(NULL);
}
```

so in above code in line 10 - thread_mutex_lock(&prev->lock); how it serves it's purpose.
Is it some standard rule to follow  ?

Thanks

Comment: That's an interesting example to use in the way it "weaves" the locking and unlocking of mutexes as it iterates through the list. It illustrates that to avoid deadlocks, mutexes always need to be acquired in a hierarchical order (in this example, the order in which they occur in the list), but do not necessarily need to be released in reverse order (in this example, the order of release varies).

Answer (score 4):

Mutexes don't lock things. You lock mutexes.

When you run `pthread_mutex_lock(&prev->lock);`, it locks the mutex, and no other thread can lock the same mutex until you unlock it. If another thread tries to, it will wait until you unlock it.

The mutex does not know about the structure. That is up to your program.

Comment: Hi, see the thing I want to clarify is pthread_mutex_lock(&prev->lock); locks how much area. I mean when you want to lock a shared variable you pass the address of variable. So here we are passing &prev->lock so how it's going to lock the whole structure. See I'm new into this so maybe very basic is not clear to me. thanks.

Comment: @Mrityu Think of a lock like a flag that can be up or down. Everyone raises the flag before they do something (waiting if it's already up until *they* can raise it) and lowers the flag when they're done doing something. The flag keeps two people from doing the same thing at the same time. It's up to the people to decide what the flag will protect. But so long as everyone agrees on what the flag protects, it works and no two people try to use the thing the flag protects at the same time. The flag doesn't know or care what it protects.

Comment: Thanks a lot... So it's actually means that whatever code is there between pthread_mutex_lock and pthread_mutex_unlock that is protected. So we can declare the mutex outise the structure and can use this mutex to protect the structure or any other variable right ? It's not mandatory to keep the mutex inside the struct ?

Comment: @Mrityu Correct. If you declare the mutex inside the structure then every structure has its own mutex (just like they have their own value and link). If you declare it as a global variable then there's only one mutex. If you declare it as a local variable then every function call has its own mutex (which makes it useless because that function call is the only one trying to use the mutex, so it never has to wait)

Comment: @Mrityu `pthread_mutex_lock(&prev->lock);` locks the mutex `prev->lock`. No more, no less. The mutex does not know about the structure.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not a 100% sure what you're asking. A mutex can be locked, and a struct can include such mutex, but I don't think that a mutex really "locks" the whole structure.

Let's simplify your question by just looking at the following struct.

```
typedef struct node1 {
    int value;
    struct node1 *next;
    pthread_mutex_t lock;
} node1_t;
```

According to the manual page of pthreads, calling `pthread_mutex_lock(lock)` tries to lock the mutex, after it is locked others cannot lock it until it is released.

In other words, after you lock the mutex, other codes will fail to lock it (before you release it), which is acting like "locking" the whole data structure. Every part of your code that accesses the structure first checks the mutex, so it acts like that we've locked the whole structure.

For more details, I advise you to read the following manual pages:
https://man7.org/linux/man-pages//man3/pthread_mutex_lock.3p.html

Comment: I mean we can declare as many mutex as many variables we want to protect and we pass the adress of that mutex varible as argument. Here we are passing &prev->lock so how it's going to lock the whole structure. From my understanding we should declare the structure variable first and then mutex for it and then it will lock the same variable. See I'm just new in this area so maybe very basic of mutex I didn't get it. I hope you got what I'm asking. Thanks

Comment: Well, actually we only lock the mutex. But every part of your code that accesses the structure first check the mutex, so it acts like that we've locked the whole structure. In other words, if you change the struct without checking the mutex, the struct is not being protected.

Comment: Yeah that's good. so we can declare the mutex outside the structure and use that mutex to access the structure. this a=way also will work right ?

Comment: Absolutely! But it seems like putting the mutex inside the struct is more convenient.